# Unable to pass a NSString from One VC to Next VC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two VCs and i want to pass resourceName from HomeViewController to SingleWebViewController. But the resourceName is getting null.

HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "SingleWebViewController.h"

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    singleWebViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    switch (selectedRow)
    {

        case 0:
        {
            singleWebViewController.resourceName=@"intro";
            NSLog(@"HtmlFileName:%@" , singleWebViewController.resourceName);
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSingleWebView" sender:self];
            break;
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     }
```

SingleWebViewController.h has the following line

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *resourceName;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.resourceName ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil] ;
        NSLog(@"%@se:" , self.resourceName);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile    ];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_webView loadRequest:request];
        _webView.delegate=(id)self;

}
```

i did notice that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is getting called before prepareForSegue. what's the cause for this. Please suggest.

Comment: Where do you `alloc init` your `singleWebViewController` in HomeViewController?

Comment: You'll want to set the `resouceName` property in `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..pass value in prepareforsegue

Edit:  if you want for different case to pass the different value then do this..i m assuming you want to segueway to same ViewController ie SingleWebViewController here.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSingleWebView"]) {
            SingleWebViewController  *singleWebViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathOfSelectedRow];
            if(indexpath.row == 0){
            singleWebViewController.resourceName=@"intro";
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 1){
               singleWebViewController.resourceName=@"some other value";
            }
            else{
               singleWebViewController.resourceName=@"something else";
            }
            NSLog(@"HtmlFileName:%@" , singleWebViewController.resourceName);
          }
        }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        selectedRow = indexPath.row;

        switch (selectedRow)
        {

            case 0:
            {

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSingleWebView" sender:self];
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSingleWebView" sender:self];
                break;
             }
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     }
```

Comment: just to add little more.. i will have to add some more switch..cases..upto..0-4..in that case it wouldn't be possible to pass the resource name in prepareforsegue..

Comment: it's possible even if you use multiple cases..if you want in case 1 the value should be set different then...get the indexpath of selected row in prepareforsegue and send different value.

Comment: the case are actually indexPath.row..will that be accessible in prepareforsegue..?

Answer (score 2):

In `prepareForSegue`, you're assigning something new to `singleWebViewController`.  If this controller is different from the controller that's already assigned in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, which I assume it is, then your property will be reset.

Instead, do this:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    singleWebViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    singleWebViewController.resourceName = @"intro";
}
```

Comment: have a look in above edit.. the above solution will not be applicable if switch.case .increase..

Comment: @Lalit_vicky Correct, you'll need to save the resource you want in an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your `prepareForSegue` you can set the property `resourceName`

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SingleWebViewController *singleWebViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    [singleWebViewController setResourceName:@"Resource name"];
}
```

Comment: This local variable will hide the instance variable.

Comment: It's not clear if ``resourceName`` is hidden or not, because the question says that ___SingleWebViewController.h has the following line___

Comment: @Lalit_vicky I think that you should set the property in your ``prepareForSegue`` method instead of in ``didSelectRowAtIndexPath``. You can create a property in your view controller, set that property in ``didSelectRowAtIndexPath`` and assign it to the view controller property in ``prepareForSegue``.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `resourceName` after `viewDidLoad` has been called. Add a custom initialiser, `initWithResourceName:(NSString *)resourceName`, and set it there. Or move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    HomeViewController *obj = segue.destinationViewController;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSingleWebView"]){
        obj.singleWebViewController = singleWebViewController;
    }
}
```